Screen reader accessibility on flutter web
hellow everyone, does Flutter support embedded accessibility for the web? like screen reader type? or do we need to use widgets like Focus, semantics and reader packages? as widgets like semantics, do not work with the web as far as I know, Any quick help related to screen reader on Flutter Web would be a great help
I tried flutter widgets like semantics and foucs and use windows narrator, but it didnt worked.
